# Tkinter GUI app frezees besides using Queue and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, queue

I've been trying to make some heavy calculations in the background of the GUI but no matter how hard I try the GUI still freezes after pressing the button. I've been looking for answers and the best one was on the [scorython website](https://scorython.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/multithreading-with-tkinter/) but it still didn't work as expected.

Here is my list of imports:

```
   1 from multiprocessing import Queue 
   2 from Queue import Empty
   3 import threading
   4 import time
   5 try:
   6     from force import Jedi
   7 except ImportError:
   8     print "Couldn't load force module"
   9 try:
  10     import stopwatch
  11 except ImportError:
  12     print "Couldn't load stopwatch module"
  13 try:
  14     import re
  15 except ImportError:
  16     print "Couldn't load regex module"
  17 try:
  18     from Tkinter import * 
  19 except ImportError: 
  20     from tkinter import *
  21 except:
  22     print "Couldn't load tkinter module"
```

and here is the code that gives me so much trouble:

```
1298     def runloop(self, x):  
1299         result = sum(range(x))`                                                                                                                                                                                   
1301         self.thread_queue.put(result)
1302    
1303 
1304     def jedi_thread_func(self):
1305         self.thread_queue = Queue()
1306         threading.Thread(target=self.runloop, args = (100000000, )).start()
1307         self.after(0, self.listen_for_result)
1308    
1309 
1310     def listen_for_result(self):
1311         try:
1312             self.res = self.thread_queue.get(0)
1313             print self.res
1314         except Empty:
1315             print "Queue empty"
1316             self.after(100, self.listen_for_result)
1317   
1318 
1319     def closest_match(self, event):
1323         
1324         self.jedi_thread_func()
```

All these functions are inside a GUI class which works perfectly fine. When I press the button linked to closest_match() the GUI freezes, despite the effort to start a new thread from within.

In the terminal output I get no errors, but neither do I get "Queue empty" callback. It just freezes for 2 seconds and prints the output.

As it is my first post here, hello and thanks in advance for quick response :)

**UPDATE:**
I finally got it working by starting the thread from another class initialized within the GUI so that they can communicate.

Comment: Your thread can't `initialize` from python. You set local variables in a thread(it's slow). Don't use local variables (inside gui class), like : `def check(a,b): return (a+b)`. Another point is can't recover large size hash(tmp) values !

Comment: @dsgdfg Thanks for the reply. Actually I made this just as an example, in reality runloop runs another function which transforms variables from another object which was initialized inside of GUI. The effect is still the same. So my main question is why can't I initialize the thread? And are you sure that thread isn't initialized if I get the correct output (from function which was executed within the thread) and no errors?

Comment: `member_1 = Tkinter_Class_Frame` , `member_2 = Build_Gui_Class` , `member_3= Jedi_Threat_Answers` did you can imagine `RAM` or `HASH_ID` ? Will be `OWERFLOW` or `UNTRACEABLE` memory values !